# Getting wrong x and y coordinates Android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
protected void setQuickActionListener(View button) {

    float density = mActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = mActivity.getWindow().getAttributes();


    button.getLocationInWindow(location);
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, " l1 " + location[0] + " l2 " + location[1],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = location[0]+ (int) (((button.getWidth() / 2) + button.getHeight() / 4) / density);
    wmlp.y = location[1] + (int) ((button.getHeight() - 60) / density);
    mQuickAction.show(button, (int) wmlp.x, (int) wmlp.y);

}
```

here the method i am using to get x y values for an ImageButton click listener to show quick action views and this the code for show method for action views.

```
    public void show(View anchor, int xPos, int yPos) {
    preShow();

    mDidAction          = false;

    int[] location      = new int[2];

    anchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    Rect anchorRect     = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + anchor.getWidth(), location[1] 
                        + anchor.getHeight());

    mRootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mRootView.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int rootHeight      = mRootView.getMeasuredHeight();
    int rootWidth       = mRootView.getMeasuredWidth();
    if (rootWidth == 0) {
        rootWidth       = mRootView.getMeasuredWidth();
    }

    int screenWidth     = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight    = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        arrowPos    = anchorRect.centerX()-xPos;

    int dytop       = anchorRect.top;
    int dybottom    = screenHeight/4;
    boolean onTop       = (dytop > dybottom) ? true : false;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlpms;



//  xPos > (screenWidth - 100

    int dyleft      = xPos;
    int dyright     = screenWidth - screenWidth/10;

    boolean onRight     = (dyleft > dyright) ? true : false;

    if (onRight) {
        if(onTop){
            yPos = anchorRect.top - rootHeight/3;
            im1 =(ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_down);
            rlpms=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) im1.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(0,rootHeight/3,0 ,0);
            im1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            Log.d("ddsaf", ""+onTop);
        }
        else
        {
            im1 =(ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_down);
            rlpms=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) im1.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(0,5,0 ,0);
            im1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //Log.d("ddsaf", ""+onTop);

        }
            xPos = anchorRect.left - rootWidth;
    } else {
        if(onTop){
            yPos = anchorRect.top - rootHeight/3;
            im1 =(ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_up);
            rlpms=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) im1.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(0,rootHeight/3,0 ,0);
            im1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //Log.d("ddsaf", "top "+onTop);
        }
        else
        {
            im1 =(ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_up);
            rlpms=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) im1.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(0,5,0 ,0);
            im1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //Log.d("ddsaf", ""+onTop);

        }
        xPos = xPos+rootWidth/4;
    }
    Log.d("ddsaf", ""+anchorRect.left);
    showArrow(((onRight) ? R.id.arrow_down : R.id.arrow_up), arrowPos);

    setAnimationStyle(screenWidth, anchorRect.centerX(), onRight);

    mWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);}
```

problem is i am getting quick action views at wrong postions ie at 0,0 once in while on infalted layout any idea why this happens below is where it has been infalted to with ***

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_xx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_separator"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:background="#333333" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            ***<com.apps.horizontalgrid.TwoWayGridView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/xx_gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
                app:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                app:gravity="fill"
                app:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/padding_small"
                app:numColumns="auto_fit"
                app:numRows="2"
                app:rowHeight="260dp"
                app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
                app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
                app:verticalSpacing="@dimen/padding_small" >
            </com.apps.horizontalgrid.TwoWayGridView>***
        </LinearLayout>
   <!--  -->
    </LinearLayout>

        <!--  -->
```

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: try View.getLocationOnScreen()

Comment: i have used it in first and second part of the code (anchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);)

Answer (score 1):

Each View object/subclass has access to methods which do exactly this.

```
View.getTop();     // Top position of this view relative to its parent.
View.getLeft();    // Left position of this view relative to its parent.
View.getRight();   // Right position of this view relative to its parent.
View.getBottom();  // Bottom position of this view relative to its parent.
```

You have to ensure that the `View` has been displayed prior to calling any of these methods, otherwise you'll get `0` or at worst an NPE.

Bear in mind, these return positions relative to a View's parent. If you want the **actual** absolute position of the View, then you will need to use the method(s):

```
View.getLocationInWindow(); // Computes the coordinates of this view in its window.
or
View.getLocationOnScreen(); // Computes the coordinates of this view on the screen.
```

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. Further information can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: thanks but i am calling it for click of Image button which is already being displayed.why is that i am getting NPE or 0 then.